# How to get one row from multiple rows in query and join another table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have three tables

**1. Card**

```
CardNo  CreateDate
12345678    01-01-15
34567876    01-05-15
45634455    01-05-16
12347689    01-02-15
43215678    01-05-15
87654445    01-05-15
```

and 
**2. Account2Card**

```
AccountNo   CardNo
123456  12345678
123456  34567876
123456  45634455
654321  12347689
654321  43215678
654321  87654445
```

one accountno have multiple cardno and I want to get last created cardNo as follows

**Need Output**

```
       
AccountNo   CardNo  CreateDate
123456  45634455    01-05-16
654321  87654445    01-05-15
```

and this result set join to another table 
**3. Transaction**

```
Id accountno   value
1   123456  5000
2   654321  6000
```

And the final output will be as follows

```
AccountNo  CardNo  CreateDate  value
123456  45634455    01-05-16    5000
654321  87654445    01-05-15    6000
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a three way join and use row number to select the records corresponding to the max card number for each account.

```
SELECT
    AccountNo, CardNo, CreateDate, value
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.AccountNo, t2.CardNo, t2.CreateDate, t3.value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.AccountNo ORDER BY t2.CardNo DESC) rn
    FROM Account2Card t1
    LEFT JOIN Card t2
        ON t1.CardNo = t2.CardNo
    LEFT JOIN Transaction t3
        ON t2.AccountNo = t3.accountno
) t
WHERE
    t.rn = 1;
```